# Why "010" equals 8?

Tags: java, binary, format, bit-manipulation

My simple question is why:

```
System.out.println(010|4);
```

prints "12"? I understand bitwise OR operator but why "010" equals 8? It's definitely not compliment 2's notification, so how to decode this number?

Comment: That is an octal literal ! More specifically : `1*8^1 + 0*8^0` = `8` !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [Java Language Specification, Chapter 3.10.1 Integer Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An integer literal may be expressed in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal
>   (base 16), **octal (base 8)**, or binary (base 2).
>
> [...]
>
> An **octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7** interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

Now you should understand why `010` is `8`.

Answer (score 13):

A leading `0` denotes an [octal numeric value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) so the value `010` can be decoded thus: `010 = 1 * 81 + 0 * 80 = 8`

Answer (score 2):

That is because java takes it as an octal literal and hence produces 12. Try `System.out.println(10|4)` and the result is 14. Because this time it is taken as decimal literal.

Answer (score 2):

As everybody mentioned here that `010` is an **Octal Integer literal** . The leading `0` specifies that it is an octal representation . Actual value will be :

> 1*8^1 + 0*8^0 = 8(decimal) = 1000(binary-only last 4 digits)

Now coming back to the SOP :

```
System.out.println(010|4);
```

Applying Bitwise OR on `010` and `4`(considering only the last 4 digits) =>

> 1000|0100
>
> = 1100
>
> = 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0
>
> = 8 + 4 + 0 + 0
>
> = 12(decimal)

Answer (score 1):

Any number in Java  which fulfill the  below Conditions -
A. number Should have three or More Digital
B.Number should Start with 0.
If above Condition are true then number treated as Octal_Base (8) Number.
Therefore,
010=(8^2)*0+(8^1)*1+(8^0)*0=64*0+8*1+1*0=8
So,
010=8

Answer (score 0):

One point you should consider that the number will be in octal if "0XX" i.e. both X are in range [0,7], otherwise it will result in "Integer number too large".