# working of these two lines of code in the program

Tags: c, string, pangram

```
total+=!used[str[i]-'a'];
used[str[i]-'a']=1;
```

It is the condition for checking the characters and saving the value in the variable total.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am not getting the function or i can say arithmetic behind these lines like ascii values and all that.

Comment: It's a pangram.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You'll learn better if you try to figure this out on your own. Work it out on paper by calculating each part of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `total` variable will contain the number of *unique* characters in the array `str`.

This happens because you increment the count(`total+=!used[str[i]-'a']`) only if you haven't already marked the character as visited. If you incremented it, you mark it as such in the next line (`used[str[i]-'a']=1`) so that you wont count it again.

The notation `str[i]-'a'` is used to shift the ascii values of the characters from *0* to *25* (instead of *97* to *122*) so that you can spare some space in the array.

Comment: ok but how the value is calculated?

Comment: Why? How? Without explanation this does not really qualify as a useful answer.

Comment: Also you make several (quite impressive, my respect) assumptions. They, too, should be explained or at least mentioned.

Comment: Not an useful answer

Comment: 'a' what this means and !used[str[i]-'a']

Comment: @Yunnosch it is a good answer for this kind of question.

Comment: +1 for a super concise answer.  I think the assumptions @Yunnosch requests are "`used` is initialized as `={0}`", and "the input is text constrained to values from lower-case `a` to lower-case `z`".  I think its fine to try to reverse-engineer the constraints of the problem statement from the attempted solution.

Comment: @Dhruv Octal numbers, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469871/why-010-equals-8.

Comment: ************
 ************
  ************
   ************
    ************              
     ************     
     ************
    ************
   ************
  ************
 ************
************